# Remote login on website using php curl

Tags: php, curl

I wants to login on website from my server using php curl. But problem is that, when i try to login using php curl, login url send me 2 action url request and it submitted 1 request. 2 action request url has different two url, first url is for email submit and 2nd url is for password submit. My code submitted only 1st url (Only email submitted), but 2nd url is not submitted password. I think so my curl code has problem.

Here is my code:

```
$url = 'https://example.com/login/email';
$userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'email=my_email_here@gmail.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$r = curl_exec ($ch);


$urll = 'https://example.com/login/password';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urll);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'Password=my_pass_here');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$rr = curl_exec ($ch);

echo $rr;

curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: you think my code is alright and i have to use cookie

Comment: also where i will use cookie, on 1st code or on 2nd code

Comment: i am not making login with. I am making direct login on gmail using php curl

Comment: i think so, you don't understand. Suppose i can do it using imap, but i wants to do it using php curl. It's a remote login on gmail account.

Comment: How can I understand if you keep removing your comments? I'll remove mine as well.

Comment: Well, correct me if I'm wrong, but this is what I think I know: If you use http(s) over curl you're logging into a website. Google uses one account for almost all its services, including gmail. So, any solution for PHP to login that should work. However, IMAP is a completely different beast: It's a mail-protocol, unlike http(s) which is a web-protocol. If you want to access your mail then IMAP is, by far, the preferred method.

Comment: This mean, i can't use php curl to login on gmai???

Comment: I didn't say that. You can. However, you will be retrieving web pages, not emails.

Comment: ok, i am not get solution from here, no problem, i will make it myself. thanks for your comment.

Comment: You're welcome. :-)